# Is there a way to stop app running on Expo Go from disconnecting after a period of inactivity?

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, metro-bundler, expo-go

I am coding an app using React Native and testing it using the Expo Go app. After a period of inactivity, it disconnects from Metro. I'd like the app to be indefinitely connected unless I end the session or otherwise. Currently, I just reload the app when this happens by pressing "r" in VS Code terminal. Is there a way I can stop this from happening? The log I get on my phone is below.

**Image of log:**

[Console Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTF5q.jpg)

**Log:**

Console Warning
Disconnected from Metro (1001: "Stream end encountered").